# use map/lambda to create dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

Here's my code:

```
 a = {}
 ins = ["foo", "bar"]
 for i in ins:
     a[i] = {}
```

Output

```
{'foo': {}, 'bar': {}}
```

Basically, I want to create a dict for each item in the list.
Is there any way to do this using map or lambda, in a more concise way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct approach is not `map` or `lambda` based, but a simple [`dict` comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
ins = ["foo", "bar"]
a = {x: {} for x in ins}
```

You could do it with `map` and a `lambda` like so:

```
a = dict(map(lambda x: (x, {}), ins))
```

but that's both slower and more verbose that a direct `dict` comprehension.

If your associated value was immutable, then [the `dict.fromkeys` alternate constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) would be a good solution, but it reuses the default value each time, so if you used it with a default value of `{}`, it would make all the keys reference the *same* `dict`, and modifying it through one key would change all the others:

```
a = dict.fromkeys(ins, 0)  # GOOD! int is immutable

a = dict.fromkeys(ins, {})  # BAD! dict is mutable
```

Lastly, a good option in many such scenarios is to [use `collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to provide defaults when you access a (previously) non-existent key. That way, you can just do:

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = defaultdict(dict)
```

and accessing any key (from `ins` or not) via bracket syntax will assign it a value of `dict()` (equivalent to `{}`) on first access.